# fixed div overflows parent height

Tags: html, css

If you have a parent div that wraps a fixed height div and a 100% height div. However, the fixed height div overlaps it's parent. Please check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wcgvt/.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forked your Fiddle and added some CSS [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HXLKD/).

What you want to do is make your container (`d3`) `position: relative` so that you can use `position: absolute` on the overflowing container, like this:

```
.d3 {
    height:100%; 
    position: relative;
}

.d3-2 {
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 54px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Here, I'm setting top to `54px` to push it down from the header, and every other dimension to `0px` to push it to the edge. Change `top: 54px` to however high you header is.

The only caveat this method has is you have to set an explicit height for the header.

---

As an aside, I hope you're using more sensible class names in your actual code; I lost track of which `d` is which a lot of times.

Comment: what is the logic of adding position:relative? I mean, are there any logic rules that explain why putting the absolute in a relative div?

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements will position themselves within the closest parent element that is _given_ a position. This is why I've given the container `position: relative` - so that `position: absolute` pushes the scrolling box to the edges of the container.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.d3 {
  height:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```